# PHP heredoc syntax

Tags: php, heredoc

I was wondering whether:

```
$foo = <<< EOT
Hello, World!
EOT;
```

is just as valid as

```
$foo = <<<EOT
Hello, World!
EOT;
```

and in particular whether this is true in all versions of PHP (or just the latest ones).

I wonder because I want to know whether a space between the `<<<` and first `EOT` identifier is syntactically valid. For instance, my PHP interpreter 5.3.10 runs this correctly but
my vim text editor does not syntax-highlight the heredoc in the same way if there is a
space between `<<<` and `EOT` (the `EOT` identifier is colored white instead of purple).

So what is the deal here? Are both legal in all versions of PHP or not?

Comment: I would always trust the compiler/interpretor before i trust a syntax higlighting parser. If it works it works.

Comment: if it works, the only thing he knows is that it works with *that* version.

Comment: Whether it works with one version or all versions, you can't rely on it working in the future unless PHP specifically allows it. EDIT - which apparently it does... according to answers below.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn how to accept answers ... if you have no idea what I'm talking about [click here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170679)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should not provide a space between the <<< and the identifier. As specified in the PHP documentation:

> (...) the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other label in PHP: it must **contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores**, and must **start with a non-digit character or underscore**.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: The space is invalid, because the identifier should be there right after the >>>; as quoted: `After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline`

Comment: That's exactly what it looks like to the parser even if you include a hundred spaces in between.

Answer (score 5):

Tabs and spaces are allowed, and apparently so are quotes:

```
<ST_IN_SCRIPTING>b?"<<<"{TABS_AND_SPACES}({LABEL}|([']{LABEL}['])|(["]{LABEL}["])){NEWLINE} {
```

[Source](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l?revision=323763&view=markup)

Edit:

- tabs and spaces are allowed from at least [2001](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l?annotate=46045#l1376)
- quotes were added in [2008](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l?r1=263595&r2=256823#l1899)

Comment: Even though this is how the code looks right now, the manual states you should only use alphanumeric chars and underscores, so this code could change in future PHP versions.

Answer (score 3):

The manual says (emphasis mine) that

> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: <<<. **After this
>   operator, an identifier is provided**, then a newline.

To me this means that the space is optional (and will always be optional), since in the language as a whole identifiers can be separated from neighboring tokens by any amount of whitespace -- including none.